# Annotation is moving to another annotation in OnAnnotationSelected

Tags: android, annotations, skmaps

I hope that someone can help me with my problem.

My code:

```
private void PrepareAnnotations():

        //Annotation 'Drink'
        SKCoordinate positionDrink = new SKCoordinate(X.X, Y.Y);

        SKAnnotation annoDrink = new SKAnnotation(customAnnoDrink);
        annoDrink.Location = positionDrink;
        annoDrink.MininumZoomLevel = 5;

        SKAnnotationView annoViewDrink= new SKAnnotationView();
        annoViewDrink.DrawableResourceId = (Resource.Drawable.icon_drink);
        annoViewDrink.Height = 128;
        annoViewDrink.Width = 128;
        annoDrink.AnnotationView = annoViewDrink;

        _mapView.AddAnnotation(annoDrink, SKAnimationSettings.AnimationNone);

        //Anootation 'Food'
        SKCoordinate positionEat = new SKCoordinate(Z.Z, A.A);

        SKAnnotation annoEat = new SKAnnotation(customAnnoFood);
        annoEat.Location = positionEat;
        annoEat.MininumZoomLevel = 5;

        SKAnnotationView annoViewEat = new SKAnnotationView();
        annoViewEat.DrawableResourceId = (Resource.Drawable.icon_eat);
        annoViewEat.Height = 128;
        annoViewEat.Width = 128;
        annoEat.AnnotationView = annoViewEat;

        _mapView.AddAnnotation(annoEat, SKAnimationSettings.AnimationNone);
```

The coordinates are not the same, they are different from each other.

```
public void OnAnnotationSelected(SKAnnotation annotation)

        if (_currentposition.Coordinate == null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Curren position is not available!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        ClearMap();

        _startPoint = _currentposition.Coordinate;
        _destiPoint = annotation.Location;

        _dragView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

        switch (annotation.UniqueID)
        {
            case 1:
                _name.Text = "Drinks";
                _description.Text = "Description of item";
                break;
            case 2:
                _name.Text = "Food";
                _description.Text = "Description of item";
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        _name.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        _description.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        _description.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, 8);

        _fab.Click += (sender, e) => 
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Button for launching the navigation!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        LaunchRouteCalculation(_startPoint, _destiPoint);
```

The function `ClearMap()` clears the route calculation.

My start point is my current position and the destination point is the location of my annotation.

I have a custom view (linearlayout) which is displayed when I click on an annotation.

The unique ID's of the annotations are read only & static. For the annotation "customAnnoDrink" it's the 1 and for "customAnnoFood" it's the 2.

In the switch case I check if the drink-icon or the food-icon is selected.

If one of the annotations is selected the custom view is displayed with the given information (name, description, etc.). The route calculation is started afterwards from my current position to the selected annotation.

```
private void LaunchRouteCalculation(SKCoordinate startPoint, SKCoordinate destinationPoint)

        SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings
        {
            StartCoordinate = startPoint,
            DestinationCoordinate = destinationPoint,
            RouteMode = SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CarFastest,
            RouteExposed = true,
            NoOfRoutes = 1
        };


        SKRouteManager.Instance.SetRouteListener(this);
        SKRouteManager.Instance.CalculateRoute(route);
```

When I click on my drink icon first, the route and the information are displayed. It is working as intended.

But when I click on my food icon now the drink icon is always moving to the food icon. I don't know why! Having this problem since monday. 
FYI: when I click on the food icon first the drink icon is moving too.

I hope that someone can help me please.
It's very frustrating...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since there's a lot of code involved - can you add this in the demo project and add a link to the modified demo project?

Comment: Sure. Just give me some time (tomorrow will be fine).

Comment: @Ando
Here are some pictures of my problem: 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/vJnJV.png (--> works fine)
http://i.stack.imgur.com/oIiBT.png (--> with the bug)